# Authenticate with google Oauth 2.0 did not match a registered redirect URI

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

I'm trying to authenticate with using *Google OAuth 2.0*, I registered my url in the *Google's Cloud Console*.

In the specs of google's *OAuth 2.0* it says: `redirect_uri`: Determines where the response is sent. The value of this parameter must exactly match one of the values registered in the *Google Cloud Console* (including the http or https scheme, case, and trailing '/').

But in the cloud console I can't put the "http", it allows me only the domain name.
The only information I guessed was the `Notification Endpoint`, the `redirect_uri` is missing. I searched the app console as well. Does anyone has a hint on where I should specify the `redirect_uri`?

Comment: I had the same problem.  I was able to fix the uri by editing it after I created the new client id.

Comment: I had the same problem too, but my problem it solved only waiting ten minutes to Google confirm the variables of the app.

Comment: I also fixed this by removing the old client ID and just creating a new one. There was no rhyme or reason - the new client ID just worked.

Comment: @QuincyLarson thanks, this happened to me too, and it might have taken quite a while for me to get frustrated enough to try this on my own...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Go to:
https://cloud.google.com/console
And you'll see the following screen. You can enter fully formed URIs as you can see in the example
[image: URI setting in Google Cloud Console]

Comment: Just to add to @unify, your URL must be character perfect, so http or ttps, trailing slash etc, must all match. You can enter many URLs, so it's best to enter every possible variation up front to save problems later.

Comment: I wonder why there's a new different address now, https://url/signin-google instead of callback, it's that new? I had to add it and it works

Comment: I had to add a trailing space to one of my urls... that was fun.

Comment: @unify the GUI seems to have changed. Where can I find this option now?

Comment: @radpin adding space sounds crazy but it works! thanx a lot!

Comment: Hi,https://mylive.stagingapplication.com starts with https but then it gives error of 400 and when changing to http ,it could not handle ExternalLoginCallback and gives 500 error. It work perfectly with https://localhost:4220/signin-google but giving on my live url