# Authenticating with omniauth-google-oauth2 redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, callback, uri, omniauth

Well I am sorry to publish such a lame question but I have managed to use omniauth with facebook, twitter and even linkedin, but I am still unable to do it with google omniauth 2.0, I found that the issue is related to the callback URI (I must add that I am testing with a local enviroment [localhost]), so I have tried to change the URI in the following ways

http:127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback/
 http:127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback 
 https:127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback/ 
 https:127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback
 http:localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback/
 http:localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback *
 https:localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback/
    https:localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback

so far I have tried with each one individually and none of these worked, it looks like the one marked with a * is the one being returned on my browser, but still receiving

```
The redirect URI in the request:
 http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback did not match a 
 registered redirect URI
```

I am therefor looking for an answer on how to perform this authentication or how to set the callback URI properly for a localhost callback. thanks in advance.

BTW: I am using Rails 4 and omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2 gems
BTW2: I have removed the "//" so these won't be treated like links

- Additional and related question is, how do I add multiple URIs on the redirect list? I have tried to add them separated by "," or simply with a blank space, as none have worked, then I don't really know what would be the propper way.

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/20732762/325564

Comment: I tried to do something like that, but it didn't work, I already manage to make it work, with a single URI, but I can't have it working with multiple URI, but thanks though

Comment: @Coronellx would you mind sharing your solution. I'm running into this same problem and the aforementioned post didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you make the access type online

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "[my key]", "[secret]", {access_type: 'online'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use

*http://localhost:3000/**users**/auth/google_oauth2/callback*

(you missed **users** in the middle)

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Using Google Drive API in more than one environment.
your 'AUTHORIZED REDIRECT URIS' should be as shown below(i am using google, yours could be google_oauth2. Changed in provider option for omniauth config file).
Every URI on new line.

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback
https://staging_server/auth/google/callback
https://production_server/auth/google/callback
```

My client_id, client_secret are in 'config/google_client.yml'.
Your 'omniauth.rb' file in 'config/initializers' should be as follows

```
google_client =  YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.join('config/google_client.yml')}")
ENV['GOOGLE_APP_NAME'] = google_client['APP_NAME']
ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'] = google_client['CLIENT_ID']
ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'] = google_client['CLIENT_SECRET']
ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SCOPE'] = google_client['CLIENT_SCOPE']

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
    { name: "google",
      scope: ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SCOPE'],
      prompt: "consent"
    }    
end

OmniAuth.config.on_failure = SomeController.action(:oauth_failure)
```

Hope this helps you.